# Opposite of a 'streaming' implementation

Tags: naming

I struggle finding a word describing a solution that is not streaming but processes everything in phases or stages resulting in keeping everything in memory. Processing something in bulk is not the right solution.

To give you an example we currently have a mechanism that has a list of identifiers. The list has like a million entries and can be loaded into memory, processed and the memory is freed or in a streaming solution the list is loaded line by line, each line is instantly processed and the memory footprint is therefore superior to the first solution.

So what is the word to describe the first algorithm / solution.

Comment: Have you ever found an appropriate term?

Comment: No not really. I know no fitting term to describe this kind of algorithm.

Comment: This is a very confused apples/oranges question.  Having a dataset in memory vs. loading the data in, are not alternatives to each other.  The data in memory still has to be loaded at some point.  There are techniques for dealing with massive datasets like mapreduce, and there is synchronous vs asynchronous processing.  Keeping data in memory for speed is a feature of most databases and key stores, in particular redis, memcache and mongodb when clustered and using sharding.  Sharding is another technique in this space.

Comment: What you suggest is an implementation detail. What I am looking is the right word to describe such a all at once algorithm correctly.

Answer (score 6):

I’m facing a similar naming issue, and decided to settle on “buffered”.